# Is it safe to drive when brakes are making a squeeky noise?

Tags: brakes, squeaking

I installed new brake disc and pads about a year ago.
I am a bit of a harsh braker but only did about 5000 miles with them.
My brakes have been making a squeeky noise for about about 3 weeks now.

I am planing on going on a day out today on a 90 mile journey.  Obviously I should have got my brakes checked earlier but I've left it to last minute and there are no garages open today.

Do you think it might still be ok for me to go on the motorway for 90 miles and back without checking the brakes?

Answer (score 2):

That's a difficult one... 5000 miles of 'harsher' braking is easily enough to wear pads down. The brakes may just be squeaking due to a small bit of debris or dust in the the braking mechanism. However they could also be squeaking due to the pads being worn out. To be on the safe side the brakes need checking out. I would recommend perhaps you postpone your journey to make sure the brakes are in a servicable condition first.

Comment: Orb is absolutely correct - you can check the discs / rotors to see if they are smooth or are suffering metal to metal contact - if they are then no trip. If the sqeaking is just from the pads and they have some material left you should be ok but you must look and get a friend to look as well...

Comment: Some pads also have a small metal stripe as wear indicator. When the pads are due, the stripe touches the disc and also makes a squealing noise, before the ground plates of the pads do.